# I have eaten the last orange that has been at home. / The orange I have eaten was the last at home

Tags: word-order

> I have eaten the last orange that has been at home.
>
> The orange I have eaten was the last at home.

Are both sentences natural, or only the second one?

Comment: Did you know that "to be at home" is only used for people? Here, we'd say: the last orange in the house. But you are asking for editing which the rules expressly say we shouldn't do. Also, since eating an orange is a one-time thing, why not use the simple past?

Comment: @Lambie "why not use the simple past" - Present Perfect puts more emphasis on the result (ie. the act of eating isn't as important as the fact that there are no more oranges at home). Perhaps someone was [saving it for breakfast](https://poets.org/poem/just-say).

Comment: @MaciejStachowski I disagree. The PP emphasizes the action, not when it happened. And the fact it is an unspecified past in terms of the present time.

Comment: @Lambie - As a British English speaker I would certainly use _have eaten_ , in the sense of 'past action having an effect on the present situation'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lambie noted, "at home" is not an idiomatic choice, but assuming you mean "the last in the house" and want to focus on word order: As is often the case, both constructions are possible, and will shift the focus slightly.

- *I have eaten the last orange in the house.* In literal terms, this puts the focus on "me" as the subject of the sentence. In practical terms, it also focuses on the resulting lack of oranges.
- *The orange I have eaten was the last in the house.* This communicates the same information, but grammatically, it puts the focus on the orange, and practically, it emphasizes the act of eating more strongly.

You might choose the first in a scenario in which the follow-up question is "What do we do now?"—"*We just ate our last rations!*"—and the second when the follow-up question is "Why did you do that?"—"*That ration you just ate was our last one!*"

Both constructions sound just a bit stilted because they avoid a contraction: "***I've eaten** the last orange in the house*" is more natural, and for the second sentence, the present perfect is a bit formal; "*The orange **I just ate***" might be a more conversational choice.

Comment: Why not: I ate the last orange in the house? Seems "the most natural".

Comment: @Lambie Sure. Arguably (though not very practically) that one shifts the emphasis just slightly too; "I've eaten" is about my present condition, whereas "I ate" is about the action. But meanwhile I'm having an interesting time asking myself why present perfect does more to make the second syntax sound formal than the first one...

Comment: The PP just tell us it is in the past without saying when at present (now). That's the difference. The emphasis is on the verb eat, not when.

Comment: @Lambie Well, with the understanding that we're splitting hairs and probably parsing intent more finely than the OP intended, it's still true that simple past emphasizes the action, while past perfect emphasizes the resultant state. "We're all out of oranges; you've eaten them all": the point is that there are none left. "We're all out of oranges; you ate them all": puts a bit more accusational weight on your actions.

Comment: @Lambie LOL—first of all, sorry, I meant "present perfect" the whole time, not "past." My point was that the present perfect sounds a bit stilted in the inverted syntax. IMO there's nothing un-idiomatic about using it in the more straightforward syntax, and of course nothing wrong with using simple past either. (Though I maintain that present perfect speaks to resultant state. "I have spoken" vs "I spoke"?)

Comment: No worries about that.//You do realize that non-natives often use the PP instead of the SP because they don't know the principal parts of the verbs....

Comment: @Lambie Heh, I do it myself all the time in Spanish when I can't remember the right form for the past tense!

Comment: Actually, I take that back: eat, ate, **eaten**. :)